# z index not working with after and before

Tags: css

I am trying to make a button animation with hovering shows yellow background from one corner then spreading around entire button. When I am using before with background color and z-index it should appear back of written text on button. But its apearing in front of it no matter what index I give. I saw other example over here, its working for them with same properties but not for me. Kindly help. ty.

```
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style media="screen">
      /* body{
        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;
        height:100vh;
      } */
      button{
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color:white;
        color:black;
        padding:20px 50px;
        position:relative;
        z-index: 2;
      }
      button::before{
        content:"";
        left:0;
        top:0;
        z-index: 1;
        height:100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color:yellow;
        position:absolute;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" >Hover</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

> z-index: -1

on the before selector

Comment: Hey button has already  a higher number , shouldn't that work too ?